# Wireless Router Doesn't Release, Update or Renew Dynamic IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Since we moved to a new place, we had no choice but to go with internet from cable provider and that in itself is not an issue, although that said, I HATE their service quality and connection, but that's neither here nor there.

My setup is as follows (did quick mock up for visual aid)
[image]

Currently the IP address hasn't changed in almost 12 months, which is weird to say the least given that dynamic IPs are supposed to change fairly regularly, although not necessarily - they don't stick around THIS LONG.

No matter how much you try to make the device release/renew, it comes back to the same IP and I don't have static IP service, so it should not be remaining like this and the ISP has confirmed that it is NOT STATIC but have no idea why its not changing either - no big help obviously and no surprise there - a cable company not able to find their ass with both hands and a GPS, say it ain't so.

I digress, so I decided to connect DIRECTLY to the cable modem to see if it makes a difference, sure enough, when connected directly to the modem, the IP changes every time (when you restart the modem or if you force release/renew) but as soon as you connect the router, it goes back to the exact same IP that has been there for almost a year, not even the new one that is clearly now on the modem.

I am at such a loss as to what the heck is going on, I honestly need some help figuring this out, it is making no sense to me. The router is NOT statically configured, its configured to grab the information dynamically from the modem/ISP. (for those visually inclined)

[image]

(and other/options)

[image]

On top of that, how can it go back to an older IP that is clearly no longer associated to the modem, even though it seems its still available for it to hog, but WHY? I have reset the router, reconfigured. I have reset the modem, reconfigured. NO CHANGE.

### Hardware/Specs:

- ISP : Charter (UGH)
- MODEM : Arris Touchstone TM1602A/CH
- ROUTER: Linksys WRT1900AC

Comment: @Tyson this sounds intriguing, would you mind elaborating slightly on that? perhaps as a more detailed answer? I would appreciate that.

Comment: Ok, got it, but what about potential MAC conflicts? I mean I am sure I can find a number that ON MY NETWORK is unique, but just thinking out loud on that one. I would had just cloned the MAC on the router to match the modem if there wasn't that pesky issue of the fact that they have different addresses on the network (as it should be) and cloning like that means that there will be other issues.

Comment: Got it, on it. Will post back my findings.

Comment: Dude? Seriously? I am so offended that you would think I am so f-ing dumb that I can't take this seriously.

Comment: Forget my help then, I do this once a week during app testing.

Comment: What help? You say roll the MAC, that's it. And then your reason for why it doesn't work is, did you reboot? Why don't you act like you actually care and earn the respect instead of demanding it for two words so far that have done nothing to help. I wasn't being disrespectful, until you followed up with that.

Comment: You proved yourself you can pull a different IP with a different MAC address by plugging your PC in directly.  When the new MAC address is saved to the router, you will instantly lose your connection to the internet until both modem and router are rebooted.  Go read dslreports.com if you want confirmation, there s more than one thread over there. So yes I seriously asked to make sure you had rebooted both, because losing connectivity is part of the process.

Comment: Correct, when connected directly to the modem, it will get a new IP each time, but NOT when "bridged" into the router and that's my dilemma and trying to figure out WHAT is forcing this IP to attach no matter what. As for the "loss of connection" obviously that happens, what I mean is that it NEVER ESTABLISHES a new or correct connection and THAT is not right or ok. If it never connects or get a new IP, then what's the point? If it forced the change, sure that would be something but it doesn't, the moment restored, it goes back and if left unchanged it will NEVER EVER complete again, so you c?

Answer (score 0):

ADSL use dynamic WAN IP's
Cable Modems use Static WAN IP's

Only shot is to clone PC MAC address and see if that changes it when router is restarted.

If you are unsure which computer was used, contact your ISP, and ask what MAC address was registered and ask to reset it.

Comment: I was actually in the process of trying that as a last ditch effort but wanted to consult everyone first to see if there was a better and less "hacky" way of dealing with it. Although I am NOT AT ALL averse to the hacky way. All options are open.

Comment: BTW, cloning the PC's MAC will lead to the machine being seen as the router and since it is not, it will cripple the network.

Comment: I think even if UPNP is enabled, it won't cause issues. How so? I do it all the time in router option page

Comment: Cloning MAC addresses is not the issue and any monkey can do that, what i am saying is that when you substitute your own machine ip X for the router ip Y and expect that all the routing tasks will magically continue? when they are coming to the pc now and not the router? That actually make sense to you?

Comment: Two end terminals or equivalent devices, works fine, but not when you are the controller for all the traffic, and end unit CANNOT take over your duties, now granted with ROUTING services available to some Windows versions, one can run a poor man's router on a PC but this is not that, so an end terminal cannot just slide into the position of a router and expect the network will function right. See what I mean?